# FirestoreRecyclerView Swipe CardView to Delete the Document

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code inside onStart() method of a Fragment:

```
final FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<NewTask, TasksViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TasksViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull NewTask model) {
            holder.setTaskTitle(model.getTaskTitle());
            holder.setTaskPrivacy(model.isTaskPrivacy());
            holder.setTaskColor(model.getTaskColor());

            //<-----  ONCLICK OF A TASK  ----->
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final DocumentReference ref = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ref.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ref.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).attachToRecyclerView(twoRecyclerView);
                }
            });
        }
```

With the provided code this happens:

When I click the CardView item, pops a Toast message of that item's Firestore document Id. But when I swipe the item, pops a Toast message of the first item that has been previously clicked. So If I try to delete an item inside onSwipe method I will constantly delete the first chosen item.

My question is: How can I delete the items I want inside onSwipe?

My main goal is to be able to delete the CardView item when they're swiped towards right or left, it doesn't have to be when that item is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple hours of turning pages I figured out the best way to set up a "Swipe to delete a CardView item from Firestore function" in a Fragment is to do it creating a new Adapter Java class.

```
public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {

public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Note model) {
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
    holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPriority()));
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item,
            parent, false);
    return new NoteHolder(v);
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}

class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDescription;
    TextView textViewPriority;

    public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
        textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority);
    }
}
```